# Labeling cells in fishnet using equivalent ("southeast") vertices in grid using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: labeling, vector-grid, vertices

I have a large grid of 0.001-degree fishnet cells. I want to label each cell using the coordinates of its own southeast vertex.

I have the coordinates for all the vertices in the entire grid, but I don't see a way to select the SE vertex for each cell except brute force. I do understand that all the vertices in the entire grid are SE corners of "some" grid cell. My challenge is to associate a single vertex with each cell for label purposes.

I did try identifying the "start", "end", and "midpoint" vertices, but I see that different cells in the grid have each of these vertices at different corners, e.g., the "start" vertex was not in the same corner for all cells, so this didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple way to do this would be to create a second fishnet that is the same size but offset by half the cell width and height.

Make it as polygons with labels but throw away the polygons and keep the label points which you can add XY values to and label.

Answer (score 0):

The cells were aligned with the geographic grid, i.e., the coordinates of each corner of the cell were multiples of 0.001 degrees. What I ended up doing was to calculate the coordinates of the centroid in each grid cell and then subtract 0.0005 degrees from each coordinate to get to the SE corner (since I'm in the northern and western hemispheres). I gave each cell a unique label using the first 3 digits of the latitude and the longitude.